# How to Set the Volume in Avplayer

Tags: iphone

I have App that play the Song from the iPod library and i also have to play the song in background so i take avplayer. but i dont set its volume. is their any way to set the volume.

Answer (score 1):

Notification popup with volume slider inside - Hoper this helps:

```
- (IBAction)volume{
    MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10, 37, 260, 20)] autorelease];

    UIAlertView *volumeAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Volume" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [volumeView sizeToFit];
    [volumeAlert addSubview:volumeView];

    /*
    for (UIView *view in [volumeView subviews]) {
        if ([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"MPVolumeSlider"]) {
            volumeViewSlider = view;
        }
    }*/

    [volumeAlert show];
    [volumeAlert release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't play an ipod-Library track using `AVAudioPlayer`. `AVAssetExportSession` has a BUG in IOS.5  so it's unable to export from iPod library in mainbundle,  So if you want to play iPod tracks, your stuck with `AVPlayer`. Sadly only Hardware buttons can control the volume of this.

Answer (score 0):

Pls check this [Adjusting the volume of a playing AVPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268949/adjusting-the-volume-of-a-playing-avplayer)

If you can use `AVAudioPlayer` you can easily use its property `volume`

Answer (score 0):

To use a slider and use this code,

In .h file write this code and don't forget to implement AVAudio framework,

```
 #import   UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import    Foundation/Foundation.h>
 #import    AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface volumechangerViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIButton *button;
    IBOutlet UISlider *volumeslider;
    NSTimer *volumetimer;
    AVAudioPlayer *audioplayer;

}

-(IBAction) pushplay;
@end
```

And in .m file,

```
-(IBAction) pushplay{

  //NSError *err;
    NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"music" ofType:@"mp3"];
    audioplayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath] error:NULL];
    audioplayer.delegate = self;
    [audioplayer play];

    volumetimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(updatevolume) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void) updatevolume{
   [audioplayer setVolume:volumeslider.value];
}
```

Hope this helps friend.

Comment: How do you think, how many times per second your updatevolume method will be fired?