# AVAudioPlayer volume

Tags: iphone, ios

Hi i'm new in ios and i want to make an app that play radio, so the app working fine, but when i tried to include the volume to the app, it's cruch and gives me this error :

```
[AVPlayer setVolume:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9d4f500
2013-05-16 09:34:47.785 RadioFM[22061:12503] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AVPlayer setVolume:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9d4f500'
```

and here is my source code that i'm using :

in PlayerViewController.h:

```
@interface PlayerViewController : UIViewController
{ AVAudioPlayer *radioPlayer; IBOutlet UISlider *Volume; }
- (IBAction)Volume:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic,retain) AVAudioPlayer *radioPlayer;
```

and in PlayerViewController.m:

```
@synthesize radioPlayer;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *RadStream=<@Radio stream>;
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:RadStream];
    NSError *error;
    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
    self.radioPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self.radioPlayer play];
    [super viewDidLoad];
```

}

and i have a slider view and on the action of this slider i have :

```
- (IBAction)Volume:(id)sender {
if (self.radioPlayer != nil)
{
    self.radioPlayer.volume = Volume.value;
}
```

}

so please can any one help me on this ? Thank you advance.

Comment: Check the Name of Your Function i think first it was `setVolume`. so disconnet binding and bind it with `Volume`. And try this to change the volume `- (void)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)slider {
  myPlayer.volume = slider.value / 100.0;
}`

Comment: actually it's was not setVolume, and to check if that true i just created a new uislider programmatically and i called the function that you wrote above and it's keep give me the same error, the new source code is : 
is viewdidload methode i create a new uislider and i called the methode above.

Comment: try this https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer

Answer (score 1):

First Check the Name of Your Function i think first it was setVolume. so disconnet binding and bind it with Volume. And try this to change the volume

```
- (void)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)slider 
{ 
myPlayer.volume = slider.value / 100.0; 
}
```

And bind your `Silder` with `UIControlEventValueChanged`. Action

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, are you using AVPLayer or AVAudioPlayer.
I am asking this question, cuz

- you have declared the `radioPLayer` as `AVAudioPLayer`.

  @property (nonatomic,retain) AVAudioPlayer *radioPlayer;
- and initialize the `radioPlayer` as `AVPlayer`

  self.radioPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

If you are planning on using AVAudioPlayer, life becomes easy. Use the `volume` property

```
self.radioPlayer.volume = iSlider.value;
```

If you are using AVPLayer, then you can refer to these steps. Not tried it, but seems like it has helped many: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6178912/942966

Comment: yes what you said is correct, i declared the radioPLayer as `AVAudioPLayer` and i initialize it as `AVPlayer` cuz `playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem` does not work with `AVAudioPLayer`, and  when i tried to use `[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];` the radio does nor even play, i don't know if the `AVPlayer` does not support that streams or what !!

Comment: `AVAudioPLayer` cant be used for streaming. `AVPlayer` has to be used.
So go ahead and declare the `radioPlayer` as an `AVPlayer`. Volume however cant be set in AVPlayer, so instead goto the link I referred to and try using `AudioMix` to set that up

Answer (score 0):

please check IBAction events is `UIControlEventValueChanged`

Comment: yes, it's UIControlEventValueChanged. and if i tried to print the values of the uisilder is print me the values as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.radioPlayer.volume = Volume.value;
```

above line have nothing any meaning. Volume.value means setVolume & because of there is no such method ,it is giving error.

assigning value according to slider movement is good one.

Comment: assigning value according to slider movement is that what i tried to do, and also when i tried to give the volume to the radio player hard coded does not work, like `self.radioPlayer.volume = 0.8;` for example.