# AVPlayer volume slider control

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, volume, avplayer

I have an app in which I stream radios thanks to a URL in a AVPlayer :

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:myURL];
    self.player = player;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                               object:[self.player currentItem]];
    [self.player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
    [self.player play];
```

What I would like is to have a slider to control the volume. I know that with an AVAudioPlayer it's easy because there's a property, but not with AVPlayer.

How could I do this ? Do I have to use AVAsset as I saw [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268949/adjusting-the-volume-of-a-playing-avplayer), and how (as I don't use them at all in my code right now)?

Thanks yall !

Comment: You might look into MPVolumeView

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a AVMutableAudioMix with the volume as specified in a UISlider valueChanged: action.  Something like this:

```
- (IBAction) sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
    AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioInputParams = 
    [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParameters];
    [audioInputParams setVolume:sender.value atTime:kCMTimeZero];
    AVMutableAudioMix *audioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
    [audioMix setInputParameters:@[audioInputParams]];
    [[player currentItem] setAudioMix:audioMix]; (from a UISlider valueChanged action)
}
```