# Control volume of iPhone in objective C

Tags: objective-c, controls, volume

is there a function or a method that i can use to control the volume level of the iPhone?
i've been searching a while for this king of method through couple of questions but u didn't find a solution.

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268949/adjusting-the-volume-of-a-playing-avplayer

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)volumeChange
{  
    [[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:volumeSlider.value];
    NSLog(@"%f===%f",volumeSlider.value,
      [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer].volume);
}
```