# iPhone AVAudio Player Volume issue

Tags: iphone

I am very beginner of iPhone Application development.But i am having knowledge in android application development and my first i phone project is streaming shout cast URL using AV Audio Player and i am using following code to streaming the URL

```
 NSString *urlstr=@"http://live64.jiljilradio.com";

  NSURL* url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlstr];

   AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];

   player = [[AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem]retain];
   [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
   NSLog(@"Play");
    [player play];
```

it works fine and i am having UI Slider for volume control by using `[player setvolume:0.5]`,my app is crashing..Please give me suggestions...

Comment: It would help to get some console output of why/how it is crashing.

Comment: -[AVPlayer setVolume:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8375c20
2013-09-02 11:45:09.753 VolumeControl[1577:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AVPlayer setVolume:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8375c20'                                                           This error message i got

Comment: Please give me suggestions for my problem..I really spends most of the time with it..I am forward to your solutions....

Comment: I'm so sorry, I just got out of bed this morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might sound counter-intuitive, but you don't set audio with AVPlayer.  You have to change volume using the audio mix with the AVPlayerItem, not with the player.

Here is a sample on how to do it [from another answer, by Jesse Crossen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6178912/793607):

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[self myAssetURL] options:nil];
NSArray *audioTracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

NSMutableArray *allAudioParams = [NSMutableArray array];
for (AVAssetTrack *track in audioTracks) {
  AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioInputParams = 
    [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParameters];
  [audioInputParams setVolume:volume atTime:kCMTimeZero];
  [audioInputParams setTrackID:[track trackID]];
  [allAudioParams addObject:audioInputParams];
}

AVMutableAudioMix *audioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
[audioMix setInputParameters:allAudioParams];

[playerItem setAudioMix:audioMix];
```

your code should end up looking something like this:

```
   AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[self myAssetURL] options:nil];
    NSArray *audioTracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

    NSMutableArray *allAudioParams = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (AVAssetTrack *track in audioTracks) {
        AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioInputParams =
        [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParameters];
        [audioInputParams setVolume:volume atTime:kCMTimeZero];
        [audioInputParams setTrackID:[track trackID]];
        [allAudioParams addObject:audioInputParams];
    }

    AVMutableAudioMix *audioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
    [audioMix setInputParameters:allAudioParams];

    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
    [playerItem setAudioMix:audioMix];

    player = [[AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem]retain];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    NSLog(@"Play");
    [player play];
```

and your volume, which is set in this line:

```
    [audioInputParams setVolume:volume atTime:kCMTimeZero];
```

also, if you save a reference to your playerItem and audioTracks, you can change the volume during playback with a call like this:

```
NSMutableArray *allAudioParams = [NSMutableArray array];
for (AVAssetTrack *track in audioTracks) {
    AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioInputParams =
    [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParameters];
    [audioInputParams setVolume:0.0 atTime:0];
    [audioInputParams setTrackID:[track trackID]];
    [allAudioParams addObject:audioInputParams];
}

AVMutableAudioMix *audioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
[audioMix setInputParameters:allAudioParams];

AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
[playerItem setAudioMix:audioMix];
```

should be from 0.0 to 1.0.

Comment: I just want another clarification.In your answer you specify asset in first line..What is that?How to declare the asset in my project??

Comment: Add added these lines to my project and assign  AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
But nothing happend.Volume not changed

Comment: I added a line to the front of my answer.

Comment: Yes i modified coding as above i mentioned..but volume not changed:(

Comment: You are setting the volume to 0 with this line:  [audioInputParams setVolume:0.0 atTime:kCMTimeZero]; so you won't hear anything.  You need to have the value be higher than 0.0, but less than or equal to 1.0 in order to hear anything.

Comment: yes you are right..Instead of setting volume as 0.0 i hearing the full sound audio that is the problem.:(