# AVPlayer change volume, vertical slider

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, avplayer

Is there a way to change the volume on avplayer using a vertical slider, MPVolumeView is just horizontal and it doesn't seems to exist a way to do that.
I could have used a custom slider: on iOS7 we have the volume property to interact with, on iOS6 it seems that the only solution is the [AudioMix Trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268949/adjusting-the-volume-of-a-playing-avplayer), but the last one seems to work only with "file" tracks not streaming content (I need to use them).
Has someone came up with an idea?

Comment: Maybe try doing a transform on MPVolumeView?

Comment: Using auto layout you are going to have a major issue

Comment: Yeah, not sure how it'd work as I haven't tried it. If I get around to testing it I'll get back to you. Maybe sitting the MPVolumeView inside a non-rotated view which has all the autolayout stuff done on it. Either way it's going to be a botch.

Comment: If Autolayout is an issue, why not just create a container view that's the correct width, then add the `MPVolumeView` as a subview, and apply the transform?

Comment: @ChrisH it could work I will look into that, thanks+

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me (iPhone 5, iOS 8.3):

```
MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(225, 270, 160, 30)];

CGAffineTransform sliderRotation = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
sliderRotation = CGAffineTransformRotate(sliderRotation,-(M_PI / 2));
volumeView.transform = sliderRotation;

[self.view addSubview:volumeView];
```

Comment: I had a placeholder view in the storyboard that I added the MPVolumeView as a subview of. I needed to ensure that the center of the MPVolumeView was the center of that view to get the rotation to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on IOS 8.4 subclassing *MPVolumeView* and placing an *UIView* in a XIB file with the position I wanted.

First subclass **MPVolumeView**.

```
@implementation UIPlayerVolume

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    CGRect originalFrame = self.frame;

    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;

    CGAffineTransform sliderRotation = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    sliderRotation = CGAffineTransformRotate(sliderRotation,-(M_PI / 2));
    self.transform = sliderRotation;

    self.frame = originalFrame;
}

@end
```